# Set selected items (rows) in QTreeView out of the model

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTreeView and a custom model, derived from QAbstratItemModel. Data is updated automatically. I want to set selected items (rows) in QTreeView out of my model. Is there a smart way to do that? Kind regards.

Comment: What are the QTreeView out of model items? Your question is not clear.

Comment: My Question is, how can I set a flag in Model, so QTreeView selects the related row in visible widget

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand your question.

Comment: Sry, its hard for me to explain: I can select a row in QTreeView by clicking on it. The selected row will be highlighted in blue  color. This selection I want to control not by click but by the model itself. So the custom model says select row 1,2,3 in view object

Comment: The concept of selection has nothing to do with the model but with the view, in this case you must use the selectionModel of the QTreeView(see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html): `QModelIndex ix = model->index(0, 0); treeview->selectionModel()->select(ix, QItemSelectionModel::Select);`

Comment: This is a pity. But thank you very much. I have to set selection depending on inner states in the model an thought there could be an easy direct way.

Comment: If you intended instead just to highlight rows (in any way) based on model data (without touching selection)... That wouldn't be complicated to achieve.

Comment: @Scheff I know, but later In want to use functionality of selected items. TreeView should show selected items in GUI and TreeView should select items in GUI.

Comment: In this case, I would connect the view to the notification about added rows and evaluate them to adjust selection. ([QAbstractItemView::rowsInserted()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#rowsInserted) seems to be suitable - though it would require a derived view. It's overridden in [QTreeView::rowsInserted()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#rowsInserted). So, call of the overridden base class method should be done first.)